# Apex Trigger - Update Lead If Contact with Same Email Already Exists

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, contact

I have a trigger implemented that will change the lead status to converted if a contact is created with the same email address. I'm trying to create a new trigger that changes a lead status to converted if the lead is inserted and a contact already exists with the same email address as that lead. I believe the following to be correct, except for this section:

```
for(Lead singleLead:leads){
    singleLead.Status = 'Converted';
}
```

I get this - Error: Compile Error: Loop variable must be of type SOBJECT:Contact at line 16 column 14. After trying almost literally every combination of lead and contact objects there I can't figure out how to make this work. I can eliminate one error message, only to create another until I'm right back where I started.

Here is the full code:

```
trigger ConvertLead on Lead (after insert) {
    List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();
    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        leadEmails.add(lead.Email);
    }

    List<Contact> leads = [
        SELECT 
            Id, Email 
        FROM 
            Contact
        WHERE 
            Email IN :leadEmails
    ];

    for(Lead singleLead:leads){
        singleLead.Status = 'Converted';
    }

    update leads;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please post the entire query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in this piece of code:

```
List<Contact> leads = [
    SELECT 
        Id, Email 
    FROM 
        Contact
    WHERE 
        Email IN :leadEmails
];

for(Lead singleLead:leads){
    singleLead.Status = 'Converted';
}
```

Notice how your`leads` variable is a `List<Contact>`. You then try to loop over that list and cast each item in the `List` as a `Lead`. You can not do this. Those items are `Contact`s.

Try something like this out instead:

```
trigger ConvertLead on Lead (before insert) {
    List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();
    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        leadEmails.add(lead.Email);
    }

    List<Contact> contacts = [
        SELECT 
            Id, Email 
        FROM 
            Contact
        WHERE 
            Email IN :leadEmails
    ];

    Set<String> contactEmails = new Set<String>();
    for(Contact contact:contacts){
        contactEmails.add(contact.Email);
    }

    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        if(contactEmails.contains(lead.Email){
            lead.Status = 'Converted';
        }
    }
}
```

First off, notice I changed the trigger to a `before insert`. The reason for this is because you will receive an error if you attempt to perform a [DML operation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml.htm) on the object a trigger is run on in an `after` [context](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). The reason this is not allowed is because it would put the code in an infinite loop.

Secondly, notice that I changed your variable names to be more descriptive. I renamed your `Contact` list variable to `contacts`. This is a core concept of [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882).

Thirdly, I used a [Set](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm) to store all matching Contact emails in the database. This will only keep one value for each of the unique email addresses found by the [SOQL query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm).

Finally, you will notice I removed all DML operations. With the trigger changing to `before insert`, there is no need to run a DML operation as the object will be inserted directly after the trigger runs.

**NOTE:** This is **not** production ready code. I have not attempted to run it and wrote it specifically on this site. You **must** write [unit tests](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) for it and do your own testing to verify it does what you intend. Good luck!

Comment: Jesse, you're amazing! Thank you so much for your help. Also, thank you for explaining the changes that you made.